# Custom javascript to elements of django-summernote widget dont work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, summernote

I have some problems with [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) application.

In toolbar of widget I have button (`.btn-fullscreen`). I want to change some blocks when user click this button, so I add javascript but unfortunatly it dont work.

```
$(".note-toolbar").on("click", ".btn-fullscreen", function () {
    // Some code
    console.log('CLICK'); <!-- Dont work
});

$(".btn-fullscreen").click(function(){
    // Some code
    console.log('CLICK'); <!-- Dont work
}
```

I notice that this problem happens only when I'm trying to contact with elements of the widget. There is no problems with elements outside of widget. What can be the reason of this strange behavior?

This is how I load static files:

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.29.0/codemirror.min.css"> {# Codemirror CSS #}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.29.0/theme/monokai.css"> {# Monokai CSS #}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "summernote/summernote.css" %}"> {# Summernote CSS #}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "summernote/django_summernote.css" %}"> {# Django-Summernote CSS #}
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.29.0/codemirror.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.29.0/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>

<script src="{% static 'summernote/jquery.ui.widget.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'summernote/jquery.iframe-transport.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'summernote/jquery.fileupload.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'summernote/summernote.min.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'summernote/ResizeSensor.js'%}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".note-toolbar").on("click", ".btn-fullscreen", function () {
    // Some code
});

$(".btn-fullscreen").click(function(){
    // Some code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find two way to archieve this.

First is new `django_summernote/widget_inplace.html` in root template folder,copy the code in `site-packages/django_summernote/templates/django_summernote/widget_inplace.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<div id='{{ id_src }}'>{{ value|safe }}</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    var {{ id }}_textarea = window.document.getElementById('{{ id_src }}-textarea');
    var {{ id }}_src = window.document.getElementById('{{ id_src }}');
    var {{ id }}_settings = {{ settings|safe }};
    var csrftoken = getCookie('{{ CSRF_COOKIE_NAME }}');

    // include summernote language pack, synchronously
    if( {{ id }}_settings.lang != 'en-US' ) {
        $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
        $.getScript('{{ STATIC_URL }}django_summernote/lang/summernote-' + {{ id }}_settings.lang + '.min.js');
        $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
    }

    $({{ id }}_textarea).hide();

    $summernote = $({{ id }}_src);
    $summernote.summernote($.extend({{ id }}_settings, {
        callbacks: {
            onInit: function() {
                var nEditor = $('.note-editor');
                var nToolbar = $('.note-toolbar');
                var nEditable = $('.note-editable');
                var nStatusbar = $('.note-statusbar');
                var setHeight = parseInt({{ id }}_settings.height)  // default
                        - nToolbar.outerHeight()  // toolbar height including margin,border,padding
                        - (nEditable.innerHeight() - nEditable.height())  // editable's padding
                        - (nEditor.outerHeight() - nEditor.innerHeight())  // editor's border
                        - nStatusbar.outerHeight();  // status bar height

                nEditable.height(setHeight);
            },
            onBlur: function() {
                {{ id }}_textarea.value = $(this).summernote('code');
            },
            {% if not disable_upload %}
            onImageUpload: function(files) {
                var imageInput = $('.note-image-input');
                var sn = $(this);
                // custom attachment data
                var attachmentData = {{ id }}_textarea.dataset;
                imageInput.fileupload();
                var jqXHR = imageInput.fileupload('send', 
                    {
                        files: files,
                        formData: $.extend({csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken}, attachmentData),
                        url: {{ id }}_settings.url.upload_attachment,
                    })
                    .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        data = $.parseJSON(result);
                        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                            sn.summernote("insertImage", file.url);
                        });
                    })
                    .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // if the error message from the server has any text in it, show it
                        var msg = jqXHR.responseText;
                        if (msg.length > 0) {
                            alert('Got an error uploading an image: ' + msg);
                        }
                        // otherwise, show something generic
                        else {
                            alert('Got an error while uploading images.');
                        }
                    });
            }
            {% endif %}
        }
    }));

    //-------YOUR CODE IN HERE------------------

    // See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
});
</script>
```

add you own script code later than `$summernote.summernote`,because summernote need be init first.

---

And the reason why you code don't work is because this:

```
    onBlur: function() {
        {{ id }}_textarea.value = $(this).summernote('code');
    },
```

the summernote code is render after your custom js,so the second way is if you delay your js for 5 seconds,then your custom is run after summernote code inited like:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".btn-fullscreen").click(function () {
        console.log("GG");
    });
}, 5000);
```

This works too and is recommend.5 seconds can be change 1 or 2,you need test a best delay on you own.